# CSS Positioning - Div in an inline-block row Jumping Down

Tags: html, css, position

I've created [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmwd3x7m/3/) to illustrate how I want the inline-blocks to line up.

```
<div class="entry">
  <div class="title">Hello</div>
  <div class="divider">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="content">This is some content that goes down to the next level when it should actually stay in the same place, just create a new line right below where it was supposed to start.</div>
</div>

.entry {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  div {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .divider {
    width: 0;
    border-left:1px black solid;
  }
}
```

In the third example of the JSFiddle, when the text overflows, it creates a new line *the whole way to the left of the parent div*, when I expected it to start right below itself.

What am I missing here?

**Update**

After trying some of the suggested methods, I came up with [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fmwd3x7m/10/) JSFiddle which does address the content box problem, *but*, the `.title` now changes it's width and won't keep the assigned widht. How do I fix that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want something like this?

just edit your css

see: https://jsfiddle.net/fmwd3x7m/9

... and you have to open and close yours keys correctly

```
.entry {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
 div {
    display: flex;
  }
.divider {
    width: 0;
    border-left:1px black solid;
  }
```

Comment: I added an update. Please see the update and [new JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmwd3x7m/10/) for the consequent issue from using `flex`.

Comment: Is because the use of your keys is wrong ... look at this other update
https://jsfiddle.net/fmwd3x7m/11/

Comment: Or if you just want indentation, tests with tables... see https://jsfiddle.net/fmwd3x7m/12/

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using [flex display](https://jsfiddle.net/fmwd3x7m/5/) ?

```
 display: flex;
```

Answer (score 0):

that is because your ".entry div" display is set to "inline-block" in the css section. set it to it to "inline" and it will behave as you expect

Comment: Inline doesn't allow me to make the `.title` div have a defined width. Is there any way around that?